# Scrapy image pipeline: How to drop image on checksum?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am scraping some images using the scrapy image pipeline and want to drop images from importing that match a certain hash.

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not image_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['image_paths'] = image_paths
    return item


item['images']     =  response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"][not(contains(@content, "Demo_600x600"))]/@content').extract()[0:self.max_pix]
```

Images:

```
url "https://www.example.de…212-B726-757P-A20D-1.jpg"
path    "full/56de72acb6c1e12ffa8644c1bb96df4edf421438.jpg"
checksum    "e206446c40c22cfd5f94966c337b56cc"
```

How can I make sure this image will be excluded within the import?

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding get_images method from imagepipeline. Image will not get downloaded if hash matches.

```
    import logging
    from io import BytesIO
    from scrapy.utils.misc import md5sum

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def get_images(self, response, request, info):
        checksum = md5sum(BytesIO(response.body))
        drop_list = ['hash1', 'hash2']
        logger.debug('Verifying Checksum: {}'.format(checksum))
        if checksum in drop_list:
            logger.debug('Skipping Checksum: {}'.format(checksum))
            raise Exception('Dropping Image')

        return super(MyImagesPipeline,self).get_images(response, request, info)
```

Comment: Thank you Sachin. I tried to implement, but it did not have any effect. The function has to be placed within class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):, right? I replaced your drop_list with:  self.pic_dummy_checksum, from within the spider: pic_dummy_checksum = [
        '671f9f34aa31bdf6bf2aeb78e16db060', ... How could I log the dropping?

Comment: try raising the exception. I have edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: There are no entries within the logfile after placing that code into class MyImagesPipeline. Where did you get this info from? I could not find any documentation at all on media_downloaded: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

Comment: There is no documentation. I am referring to scrapy code of file pipeline. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py

Comment: Do you have correctl loglevel set? Try print and running manually on cmd.

Comment: Interesting. I have set LOG_ENABLED = True in settings.py and run: scrapy crawl name -s LOG_FILE=mylog.log Everything else seems to be logged.

Comment: Do you have LOG_LEVEL in settings? Set LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'

Comment: I have put this line now into settings and inside the logfile there are DEBUG notices. However no entry if I grep for Verifying and I could not see any entry. It seems like it never reaches this function. The files are within cache. Might this be a problem?

Comment: It turned out ImagePipelines use get_images method instead of media_downloaded.  If files are in cache, then get_images would not be called. You can simply filter them in image_paths list of item_completed method.

Comment: Still no luck. I disable cache, changed to get_images but still no log entry and the crawler imports all items in the drop list. Double checkd twice. Any other ideas? This seems to be a tricky one!

Comment: You probably already have images downloaded. Scrapy does not attempt to download if file exists. I tested the code with empty image folder and it seems to be working.