# Scrapy ImagesPipeline is exporting dropped images

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I am using the ImagesPipeline to scrape and download some images after filtering for their checksums.
The log is showing the right number of images dropped and scraped but in the folder all images are being saved.

pipelines.py

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem



class NikeNamePipeline(ImagesPipeline):


    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):

        urls = ItemAdapter(item).get(self.images_urls_field, [])
        return [Request(u, meta={'imagename': item.get('image_name')}) for u in urls]

        
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
                    
        return f"full/{request.meta['imagename']}.jpg"


    def thumb_path(self,request,thumb_id,response=None, *, item=None, info=None):

        return f"thumbs/small/{request.meta['imagename']}.jpg"
    

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):

        checksum = results[0][1].get('checksum')
        
        if checksum == 'e00d8ea516c4246c25930163241ec745':
            
            raise DropItem('do not download')
```

settings.py

````
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'nike_name.pipelines.NikeNamePipeline': 1,
}


IMAGES_STORE = 'C://Users/USER/scrape_projects/nike_name'

DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 1200

IMAGES_THUMBS = {
    'small': (50, 50),
    }
    ```
logs
````

{'downloader/request_bytes': 435600,
'downloader/request_count': 1200,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1200,
'downloader/response_bytes': 14493780,
'downloader/response_count': 1200,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1200,
'elapsed_time_seconds': 23.401415,
'file_count': 600,
'file_status_count/downloaded': 600,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 22, 11, 15, 42, 53919),
'item_dropped_count': 598,
'item_dropped_reasons_count/DropItem': 598,
'item_scraped_count': 2,
'log_count/DEBUG': 1802,
'log_count/INFO': 10,
'log_count/WARNING': 598,
'response_received_count': 1200,
'scheduler/dequeued': 600,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 600,
'scheduler/enqueued': 600,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 600,

```
The result in the log is exactly how it should be , 598 images dropped and 2 scraped but all 600 are getting exported in the folder.

I tried the following :
 - the solution on stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460722/scrapy-image-pipeline-how-to-drop-image-on-checksum, but that didn't work for me
```

Comment: Once the pipeline reaches the `item_completed` method the file has already been downloaded.  I don't know if it is possible to calculate the hash value prior to downloading the file.  You might be better off using that method as a way to remove the image if the hashes aren't a match.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I am removing then the images from the folder based on their hash with os.remove.

But I still think there should be a way of avoiding the download itself

Comment: that would only be possible if the hash value has already been pre-calculated and available from some source, otherwise you have to download the file in order to calculate the hash value.